# Incrementing a numpy 3-D array with repeating 2-D positions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2-D numpy array as follows,

```
vol_coords = np.array([[  2,  68],
                       [ 79,  30],
                       [  2,  68],
                       [ 79,  30],
                       [ 79,  30],])
```

I would like to increment the positions given in the above array in a 3-D volume where the z position is fixed. Imagine it to be a slice of the volume in the x-y plane.

```
 voxel_space = np.zeros((100, 240, 180))
```

The increment in the 3-D volume is equal to the number of times the position appears in the earlier array. Suppose I decide to increment the Oth Z position in the 3-D array, then the expected results are as below:

```
>> voxel_space[0, 2, 68]
2.0
>> voxel_space[0, 79, 30]
3.0
```

I have been using the following approach,

```
voxel_space[0 , vol_coords[:, 0], vol_coords[:,1]]+=1
```

However the above approach always gives me a value of `1.0` and does not take into account repetitions in the `vol_coords` array. Could someone please tell me how I could solve this problem. I would prefer not using a for loop and iteratively solving the problem.

Comment: You can either use `np.add.at` or `np.bincount` + `np.ravel_multi_index` + `np.unravel_index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches with `np.add.at` and `np.bincount` could be proposed -

```
def addtoarray_addat(voxel_space, vol_coords, z_index=0):
    shp = voxel_space.shape 
    idx = vol_coords[:,0]*shp[2] + vol_coords[:,1] + z_index*shp[2]*shp[1]
    np.add.at(voxel_space.ravel(),idx,1)
    return voxel_space

def addtoarray_bincount(voxel_space, vol_coords, z_index=0):
    shp = voxel_space.shape
    idx = vol_coords[:,0]*shp[2] + vol_coords[:,1] + z_index*shp[2]*shp[1]
    voxel_space += np.bincount(idx, minlength=np.prod(shp)).reshape(shp)
    return voxel_space
```

If we are filling into a zeros initialized array, it would be simpler as we feed in the output shape instead -

```
def addtoarray_bincount_zerosinit(shp, vol_coords, z_index=0):
    # shp is shape of voxel_space, desired output
    idx = vol_coords[:,0]*shp[2] + vol_coords[:,1] + z_index*shp[2]*shp[1]
    voxel_space = np.bincount(idx, minlength=np.prod(shp)).reshape(shp)
    return voxel_space
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Any advantages of one method over the other?

Comment: @AshishRaoM I would go with bincount ones for many repeated indices for performance.

Comment: Hmm, but in my case addat performs 3 times faster than bincount.

Comment: @AshishRaoM You also need to account for `np.zeros((100, 240, 180))` initialization inside the timings for add.at one.